# EACCES permission denied error in android when opening file on local storage

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have used SU to take a screenshot and save it in `/files/screenshot.jpg` of my app directory. I went in and changed the permissions to `rw-rw-rw`. Next I tried using this library `https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper` to open the picture to crop it. This worked on Lollipop and before but is failing in marshmallow. I'm sure this has to do with the new permission handling in marshmallow (currently targeting v19 though). I keep getting:

```
/data/user/0/com.xlilcasper.perkolator/files/screenshot.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I can't seem to find any permissions I would need in order to access a file in my own apps directory. Just to make sure I did request:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and also checked I had permissions with:

```
requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: On Marshmellow you should ask for runtimepermissions for READ and WRITE. Or go to the settings of your app and set them manually on on.

Comment: How are you getting the path?

Comment: context.getFilesDir()   I have already requested permissions.